# $broadcast and $on is not working on template which is based on ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got problem to *broadcast* event from parent scope to child scope which I think the root core might be child controller is not initialized.

Assume I have `html`:

```
<div ng-controller="ParentController">
  <button type="button" ng-click="show()">Show Template</button>

  <div ng-if="showTemplate">
    <div ng-include="'template.html'" ng-controller="ChildController"></div>    
  </div>

</div>
```

and controllers:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller('ParentController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {   
  $scope.show = function(){
    $scope.showTemplate = true;
    $scope.$broadcast("showEvent", 1);
  };

}]);

myApp.controller('ChildController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.$on("showEvent", function(event, id){
    alert(id);
  });
}]);
```

When the button `Show Template` is clicked, the flag `showTemplate` is set to show the template, also an event `showEvent` is broadcast-ed to child scope.

But the scope in `ChildController` cannot catch this event since the child controller might initialize later.

Is there any way to work around this?

The code in here: http://plnkr.co/edit/HV6aco

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using `ng-if` the DOM nodes with the `ChildController` are just not present at the time when the event is fired.

I see two possibilities:

1. Move the `ChildController` somewhere above the `ng-if`
2. use `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`

See the updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/NluFBJ

However, if you are really only interested in getting notified when the template is being created, then I would suggest to just go for @Roy Daniels solutions and just don't use `$broadcast`/`$on` at all and instead put the code you wanted to run directly into the `ChildController` since that will be executed anyway each time the template is being created.

Comment: Thanks for your solutions, the second approach is really good fit for my case

Comment: I'm happy I was able to help you :)

Answer (score 6):

Wrap the call of broadcast into a `$timeout` and you are good to go i believe

```
$timeout(function() { $scope.$broadcast("showEvent"); },0);
```

Comment: FYI, the [default value of the second parameter](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/timeout.js#L29) to `$timeout` is `0`.

Comment: As explained in the correct answer, the controller to catch the event is not created by the time of broadcast. So by adding a timeout we put a delay before the broadcast.

Comment: In my case I've to use 10 as the $timeout value. With 0 still not working

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use $broadcast/$on here. Every time you show your template the code in ChildController will be initialized and run.

Take a look at this Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/liON6k?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the thing is I need to send `1` from parent to child, I have updated my question

Comment: In that case, I guess the `ng-show` option might be better suited. If you were just interested in getting notified when the template was created, I would say @Roy's solution was the best.

Comment: Oh okay... Yeah your original question didn't specify that. In that case @Christoph answer is best.